# Ubuntu 22.04 Apt-Get Update cant fetch updates

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04

I've been trying to update my linux subsystem in Windows and it just keeps crashing due to connection failure. I can ping the servers and even open them from my browser so I assume neither the connectivity nor a potential block on port 80 is leading to this. I did this from multiple networks too so it definitely cannot be the firewall. At this point I am assuming that it is the antivirus but I want to avoid deactivating it just for this install. It is not necessarily because I think it is unsafe but mainly because I am sure the admin will get to know somehow and I really want to avoid having explanations. Any good suggestion?

I tried this not just with the local servers btw. The main servers also lead to the same issue so changing the address does not seem be of a lot of help in this situation.

```
Ign:1 http://us.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://us.security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
```

Comment: There's two problems here.  (1) You have `us.security.ubuntu.com` which is **wrong** - that should be only `security.ubuntu.com`.  (2) Your internet is being blocked somehow or something is denying you connecting to the main repositories on your Internet network - potentially your antivirus or something else.  You'll have to simply *turn off* your Antivirus to start with to see if that fixes the problem.  As for your firewall, the firewall *can* block connections outboudn if the host is Windows, despite 'the network' you're on - make sure your system permits VirtualBox or such out the door.

Answer (score 2):

the domain name us.security.ubuntu.com is not resolving maybe the server is down or dns problem

I checked it with dnswatch
https://www.dnswatch.info/dns/dnslookup?la=en&host=us.security.ubuntu.com&type=A&submit=Resolve

for us.archive.ubuntu.com respond normally check the result:

https://www.dnswatch.info/dns/dnslookup?la=en&host=us.archive.ubuntu.com&type=A&submit=Resolve

try to change mirror via GUI

Open the Software & Updates application, then click on the “Download From” drop down box. ...

Manually scroll through the list and select your desired mirror, or alternatively just click the “Select best server” button to let Ubuntu do the work for you.

also follow this [article](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/how-to-change-ubuntu-repository-mirror-sources.html)

try to clear apt cache

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> us.security.ubuntu.com +all
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 53995
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.security.ubuntu.com.                IN      A

;; Query time: 10 msec
;; SERVER: 172.24.208.1#53(172.24.208.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 27 05:11:04 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

Not resolving anywhere it looks like

For comparision the one who is working:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47494
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  0       IN      A       91.189.91.38
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  0       IN      A       91.189.91.39

;; Query time: 90 msec
;; SERVER: 172.24.208.1#53(172.24.208.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 27 05:16:04 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

I would comment out the not working mirror in your sources.list for now.