# Some repos fail to update on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources

```
**sudo apt update
Atingido:1 htt-p:-//br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Obter:2 http:-//br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                      
Atingido:3 htt-ps:--//repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                   
Atingido:4 http--s://repo.steampowered.com/steam beta InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Atingido:5 htt--ps:-//dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                      
Obter:6 ht-tp://-b-r.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99,8 kB]                                                                                                              
Atingido:7 h-ttp:/-/security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                         
Obter:8 ht-tp://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/codestation/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease [1.533 B]                
Ign:9 htt-p://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:10 h-ttp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:11 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Obter:9 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [91,0 kB]
Err:9 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata         
  File has unexpected size (90656 != 91016). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:91016 [weak]
   - SHA256:828455da8c15b1c5b7b48052f5205df9176435d77244acec9c445e27b0957895
   - SHA1:23424ef3e388026c6f89b49cc847b089186cdf92 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ef3b7d80cca9d90d4c7ce92866907dbb [weak]
  Release file created at: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 11:16:48 +0000
Obter:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,2 kB]         
Obter:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,2 kB]         
Obter:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,2 kB]
Obter:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,2 kB]
Obter:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95,2 kB]
Err:10 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata     
  
Obter:11 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]         
Err:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata     
  
Ign:16 h-ttp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata     
Obter:16 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12,6 kB]
Err:16 ht-tp://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
  File has unexpected size (12468 != 12560). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:12560 [weak]
   - SHA256:44c613fa3164b2637286db7e58b18dfd04bca32f09e80eeb5ef77f9fb7c902a7
   - SHA1:d72edacf5ad112d6e0e2a127334f64e02745ffa2 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ad6b7a054346db0e8d078af7613a7b0d [weak]
  Release file created at: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 11:17:08 +0000
Atingido:17 h-ttps-://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease      
Atingido:18 htt-ps://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Baixados 216 kB em 3s (81,1 kB/s)
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
W: ht-tps://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: Falhou ao buscar http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (90656 != 91016). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:91016 [weak]
    - SHA256:828455da8c15b1c5b7b48052f5205df9176435d77244acec9c445e27b0957895
    - SHA1:23424ef3e388026c6f89b49cc847b089186cdf92 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ef3b7d80cca9d90d4c7ce92866907dbb [weak]
   Release file created at: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 11:16:48 +0000
E: Falhou ao buscar h-ttp-:-/-/br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Falhou ao buscar ht-tp:-//br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Falhou ao buscar htt-p-:-/--/br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  File has unexpected size (12468 != 12560). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 200.236.31.4 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:12560 [weak]
    - SHA256:44c613fa3164b2637286db7e58b18dfd04bca32f09e80eeb5ef77f9fb7c902a7
    - SHA1:d72edacf5ad112d6e0e2a127334f64e02745ffa2 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ad6b7a054346db0e8d078af7613a7b0d [weak]
   Release file created at: Mon, 25 Jul 2022 11:17:08 +0000
E: Falhou o download de alguns ficheiros de índice. Foram ignorados ou os antigos foram usados em seu lugar*
My sources.list:
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main restricted
# See htt-p-:-//helpubuntucom/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb ht-tp:-/--/--br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src h-t-t-p-:-/-/-b-r.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb ht-tp:-/--/-b---r----.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src htt-p-:-/-/b-r-.-archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb htt-p:/-/--brarchive-.u-buntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src htt-p-:-/-/-b-r.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb htt-p-:-//-br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http-:-//brarchive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http-:-/-/-brarchiveubuntucom/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://brarchiveubuntucom/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http-:--//brarchiveubuntucom/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://brarchiveubuntucom/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb ht-tp://br-.archive.u-buntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src h-ttp-://b-r.archive.-ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb ht-tp://secur-ity.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb ht-tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb ht-tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src ht-tp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.*
```

I don't know what is happening, the last things I did was to install the Multipass from snap and add the Microsoft's Edge browser update repo.

*Please ignore the [-] on the links

Comment: read my reply on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415990/ubuntu-22-04-apt-get-update-cant-fetch-updates/1415994#1415994)

Comment: Mirror syncs occur. That's how mirrors update. Be patient and let the sync complete. Or try a different mirror.